# Efficient way to find path between any two nodes in a undirected graph

Tags: graph, breadth-first-search

I got an undirected graph with such that all the edges with same weight and all the vertices are connected. I want to find path between any given pair of vertices.

A less efficient solution is:
To perform BFS starting with one of the vertices, keep track of the visited vertices till the destination vertex is reached. This would perform in  O(V + E). But this will have to be done for every pair of vertices given. Hence if there are M number of queries to find path, complexity would be O(M *(E+V)).

Can we do it better? Is it possible to leverage the output a BFS and solve the rest?

Answer (score 0):

As you state that the graph is connected, it is not necessary to call a searching algorithm for the graph more than once. It is sufficient to use a single call to BFS (or DFS, this should make no major difference) to generate a spanning tree for the input. As from your problem statement it is apparently not necessary to find a *shortest* path between the vertices, any pair `(a,b)` of vertices is connected via the path from `a` to the root `r` of the spanning tree and the path from `r` to `b`.

The runtime would be  `O(V+E)`, namely the runtime of te searching algorithm; an additional computational cost might be necessary for the generation of the actual paths themselves.